# Return a document with the max value on a number field using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

If I have a bunch of documents for instance

```
{
  _id: mongoId,
  subcatId: mongoId,
  viewCount: 2
}
```

`_id` is unique but `subcatId` isn't.

If I wanted to return each document that had the highest viewCount per subcatId, how would I do that using aggregation with Mongoose/MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  // Sort the docs by viewCount descending so that the highest ones come first
  {$sort: {viewCount: -1}},
  // Group by subcatId and take the first doc from each group
  {$group: {_id: '$subcatId', doc: {$first: '$$ROOT'}}}
])
```

The [`$$ROOT`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) system variable was added in 2.6 and represents the whole document being processed at that stage in the pipeline.  All system variables are referenced with the `$$` prefix.

For older versions of MongoDB, you need to individually add each field you need to the `$group`:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  {$sort: {viewCount: -1}},
  {$group: {
    _id: '$subcatId', 
    doc_id: {$first: '$_id'},
    viewCount: {$first: '$viewCount'}
  }}
])
```

Comment: What exactly is '$$ROOT' I'am having a hard time finding the documentation related to that term.

Comment: I get this error uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.",
 "code" : 16410,
 "ok" : 0
} Also you might want to include : next to $group

Comment: @AustinDavis `$$ROOT` was added in MongoDB 2.6 so if you're running an older version you'd have to include each field in the `$group` individually instead.

Comment: Ya I'm using 2.4.11 :( so if I wanted to also include the documents _id and viewCount in the return how would you recommend to do that?