# need to return x number of documents from a $aggreagate group stage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

If I have a bunch of documents

```
{_id: mongoId,
submittedTo: mongoId,
viewCount: 2
}
```

If I wanted to return x number of document(s) that had the highiest viewCount to Lowiest per submittedTo. How would I do that using aggregation with mongoose/mongodb?

I learned about $first from this question
[Return a document with the max value on a number field using MongoDB aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811178/need-to-return-a-document-with-the-max-value-on-a-number-field-using-mongob-aggr) but the use case for it seems to be nullified when you need to return more than one document per the $group's _id.

So far I have

```
{$sort: {viewCount: -1}};

{$group : {_id: '$submittedTo'}};
```

but don't know what else I need to add to the group stage, to achieve the needed effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good way to do this in one aggregation that covers every submittedTo value at the same time. It would be difficult or impossible to sort each `submittedTo` group's collection of `viewCount` values independently of the other groups and to limit each group's number of results independently of the other groups. However, it's easy enough to do for one `submittedTo` value with a find query:

```
db.collection.find({ "submittedTo" : <some id> }).sort({ "viewCount" : -1 }).limit(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $limit to obtain the first x results.

```
{$limit: x}
```